# Number of simple cycles(cycles with no repeating node) of odd length in a complete graph with 17 nodes.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I know that the number of simple cycles of length $k$ from $n$ nodes is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot\frac{1}{2k}$.

So i should add $$\frac{17!}{(17-3)!} \cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{17!}{(17-5)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2\cdot5} + \cdots +\frac{17!}{(17-17)!} \cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot17}$$right?

But the problem is it is tedious to find this sum. Is there other way to solve this problem or is there a way to compute this sum faster?

Comment: Are the $n$'s in your denominators supposed to be $17$?

Comment: @Arthur yes that is correct i forgot to replace

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{17!}{(17-3)!}$ can be simplified to $17 \cdot 16 \cdot 15$, and similar can be done for each other fraction. Collect common factors and simplify.